# Getting args[1] from linux terminal in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm writing a program that can get a flag containing 2 chars for example "-c" and a file name or just the file name. I'm trying to parse the flag and check if it is correct but I get `mismatch in operand sizes` error on the line `mov ebx, BYTE [ebx]`.

the code:

```
_start:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, 0
    add ebx, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, BYTE [ebx]
    cmp ebx, '-c' ; -c  given
    je print_char_num
    
    jmp print_file_content ; -c not given
```

How can I parse the first argument from the terminal correctly?
Thanks!

Comment: Set your answer as accept since it fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix it, this is the current way tp get argv[1]:

```
_start:
    push ebp 
    mov ebp, esp
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ebx, [ebp+12] ; argv[1] - the -c flag if given
    movzx ebx, word [ebx]
    cmp ebx, '-c' ; - is  given
    je print_char_num
    
    jmp print_file_content ; -c not given
```

I move word to ebx, since I want to get the first 2 chars from the argv[1] (the '-c' flag)